# Having issues with jquery on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am having issues getting some jquery to work on internet explorer...sometimes it seems to work, and sometimes it doesn't seem to work.  Having no issues with chrome/firefox though, i don't understand what can be the cause of these issues.

I am not including the jquery source from the file, but rather putting the file inline the file.  I have split it up into a few lines like they do in the actual jquery.min.js though, so that shouldn't be causing any issues.

The rest of the HTML is all on one line though, could the length of this line be causing issues?  When clicking some of the links on the page and the listners should activate on the click() function it just opens up the windows explorer tool instead of catching it and having e.preventDefault() activating.

I could show you guys the source for the JS, but I know that is working properly, as I said its fine on chrome/firefox, so I feel there is some hidden issue I don't know about for internet explorer.  I have listed all of the possible details and causes of this issue....help please?  Thanks to any information and I can answer any questions to get this working :)

EDIT:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="application/octet-stream" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><!-- JQUERY 1.7.2 HERE --></head><body><!-- HTML IS HERE WITH LOTS OF DIVS --><!-- JQUERY CODE HERE --></body></html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the IE developer console for error messages?

Comment: 1. Are you sure you have defined a doctype? 2. Please post a test case that shows that it does not work in IE9

Comment: I posted my header stuff @Bram, mplungjan, Piyush if I say the code isn't going to help you, it's not going to help, i do this for a living.  I know what information is needed and what's not.  I am looking for known issues with IE, not typos because it's working on the other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any console.log statements, take them out.  If developer tools are enabled (F12), IE will work.  Otherwise, it will stop executing code with console.log.

The best way to test this is open the developer tools, and then see if the code works in IE.  If it does, then removing the statements should fix the problem.

Comment: I just removed my console.log statements, sometimes on IE9 I get this message: "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX Controls", when I hit yes it will allow the jquery to work, but I shouldn't have to do this...I've never hard this issue in internet explorer with my other web projects either....

Comment: Oh yeah, something else important is that this is being run by the file:\\ and not by a localhost, since the final version of this product will just be network accessed...

Comment: @MasterGberry: this often happens when you are testing a website locally. When you get it live, these messages will disappear. Nothing to worry about!

Comment: It's not ever going to go live.  It's an internal network meant soley for the company I am working at.  So I need to get this working on a network level, I found this on the internet: `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->` for internet markup tags?  I can't seem to get this to help either though =/

Comment: I don't think you can work around this. It's the security settings of IE that don't allow you to run these scripts. You can disable it though. Just Google the warning.

Comment: @MasterGberry, I would seriously consider hosting from a server on your network.  The level of expertise is not very high, you may simply download and install a WAMP server or IIS server (if you are using windows).  The hardest part is either reserving an IP with DHCP, or getting your network folk to allow you a static IP address.

Comment: I want to, but my company won't put a side a server/ip/whatever needed for it, so there is nothing I can do to do this...

Comment: But that is my point... you only need to hook the computer onto the network.  If it is acting as a server (which is a simple software load), just plugging it into the network is 90% of "work".  I have done the same, by taking a decommissioned Pentium IV desktop (which would have been recycled) and it now serves complex web pages.  In my case, I built a LAMP server (based in Linux) but the same could happen with a computer running something as old as Windows 2000.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issues with javascript, that was running perfectly under Chrome and Firefox and seemed to totally not load on IE, and I was amazed to find out that Internet explorer is not executing your javascript if you have console.log in your code, used for debugging (or other purposes), and thanks to stackoverflow I understood about this.

So if everything in IE seems to work fine with Dev. tools open (F12) then after removing console.log from your scripts everything will be ok.